# A log4j logger with multiple buffers

Tags: log4j

I want to create logger that will handle messages from multiple threads. Threads will be executed by ExecutorService and they will stay alive for a few minutes. Each of them performs activity which is completely independent from other threads. When I'm reading log, I want to see separate messages for each of threads in consistent state but also have all of them in a single file. So I want to use only one instance of logger (as I will log into a single file) but each thread will communicate his own buffer for this logger. When thread is about to finish execution he should flush the buffer - so when I read the log, the messages originating from this thread will not be interspersed with other threads' messages.
How can I achieve it with log4j? I tried to search docs but either I can't specify my requirements well or this kind of feature is not supported.